# React' findNodeHandle method stopped working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-native, react-native-ios

After upgrade to *0.26.0-rc* version, this line:

```
React.findNodeHandle(this.refs.myRef)
```

Throws this error message:

> Unhandled JS Exception: _react2.default.findNodeHandle is not a
>   function.

I'm importing React with this:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Docs [still say](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemethodsmixin.html#measurelayout):
*"As always, to obtain a native node handle for a component, you can use React.findNodeHandle(component)."*

Comment: Version `0.26-rc` of what? Which docs say that?

Comment: React Native , https://github.com/facebook/react-native

Comment: Any way you can show some more code?

Comment: @NaderDabit , nothing special there: https://jsfiddle.net/44fk655d/

Comment: Are you supposed to import `react` or `react-native`? Seems like you are importing `react`. And to be clear, you are saying this works fine on `0.25` but fails on the release candidate?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Now the function may be used without object:

```
import {
  ...
  findNodeHandle,
  ...
} from 'react-native';
```

And call it directly:

```
findNodeHandle(this.refs[refName])
```

Answer (score 34):

You have to import ReactNative as well.

```
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
...
ReactNative.findNodeHandle(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import {
  ...
  findNodeHandle,
} from 'react-native';

var RCTUIManager = require('NativeModules').UIManager;

var view = this.refs['yourRef']; // Where view is a ref obtained through <View ref='ref'/>
RCTUIManager.measure(findNodeHandle(view), (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
  console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
  console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
  console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
  console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
  console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
  console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)
})
```