# Undefined is not a function(React.findNodehandle)

Tags: react-native

I upgraded ReactNative from 0.2.1 to 0.26.3 and then ran the project on both Android and iOS. It worked fine in iOS but in Android, it throw out an error :

> Undefined is not a function(React.defalut2.findNodehandle)

Also tried  `{import ReactNative, {} from 'react-native';}` and `ReactNative.findNodeHandle(component)` ; it did not work neither.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196734/react-findnodehandle-method-stopped-working

Answer (score 14):

You can now import the function directly:

```
import {
  ...
  findNodeHandle,
  ...
} from 'react-native';
```

And use  without class:

```
 findNodeHandle(ref)
```